# Packager for packing html css js file to .exe

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, sencha-touch, package

Is there any packager available in market to package html, css, js file into some .exe.

i am making a game using jquery/sencha so the requirement is to zip it into a .exe (to make it browser and platform independent). Any ideas folks....i tried googling but didn't get anything..

Comment: What about using a self extracting zip ?

Comment: zip is something different...zip will just tie the files together and will not execute itself by just double clicking on it....

Comment: You can't ask to create a `.exe` and want it to be platform independent. You can't have what you want unless you package the browser with it which wouldn't be browser independent.

Comment: ok...i will put chrome inside that....now tell me the option if any available...

Comment: And what about searching a bit by yourself? You can't say it'll be chrome since Windows/Linux/... version ain't the same. Just give people the files and they'll open it with their own browser.

Comment: Sencha application runs only in chrome so i can't allow people to use their browser....and about Windows/Linux...i am targeting for windows only in the first go....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a tool available called [siteinfile](http://www.abyssmedia.com/siteinfile/).
Its works but had limitations.